# How to fix circular import here?

Tags: python, import

I have two files `mainfile.py` and `lists.py`. `mainfile.py` has a class `Foo` with methods that depend on lists. So I'll feed some lists from `lists.py` to it. But one of the lists from `lists.py` will have an element that uses a method from class `Foo` in `mainfile.py`. Something like this:

```
# mainfile.py
import lists

list_1 = lists.list_1
list_2 = lists.list_2

class Foo:
    method_1(lst1, lst2, lst3):
        pass
        # does stuff with those lists

    method_2():
        pass
        # will be used on lists.py
```

```
# lists.py
import mainfile

list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['depending', 'on', mainfile.Foo.method2(), 'method']
```

Initially I was doing `from mainfile import Foo`. However, I changed it to just `import Foo` just like an answer here on SO said. But it still does not work. When running `mainfile.py`:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'lists' has no attribute 'list_1' (most likely due to a circular import)

I've tried moving the `import` to the end of `lists.py`, but then `mainfile` in `mainfile.Foo.method2()` is not defined.

**What should I do here? refactor something? or am I importing those files the wrong way?**

P.S. I'd do this all in one file, but `lists.py` will eventually have a lot of lists in it, so I'd rather keep it separate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both files import each other, which causes a kind of recursive loop of import. Python can't finish importing `lists.py` without finishing importing `mainfile.py`. And it can't import `mainfile.py` without finishing importing `lists.py`, so its stuck.

There are two solutions to this kind of problem.

First, put it all in one file and don't do imports.

Second, define a third file with things that the other two both need but that does not need anything from the other two.